# How to reference shared resources in Nuget

Tags: nuget

I am new to NuGet and I want to make a package that contains C++ libraries and C# interop libraries. When someone installs the package, I want that the interop get added to the references, and all the C++ libraries get copied to the release folder. Is there a way to do that easily?

Also, I would prefer if the C++ dlls were not distributed to each an every project in the solution, is there a way to keep them in a shared project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, NuGet has the concept of explicit assembly references. It allows you to specify exactly what assemblies in the 'lib' folder that will be added as references to the project. Other assemblies in 'lib' that are not specified will stay as is.

See the section "Specifying Explicit Assembly References" on this page: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference